# WFFM Form verification does not show right error message

Tags: wffm

Sitecore version: Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519)
WFFM version: Web Forms for Marketers 8.1.rev. 160523
XM environment

I've configured a login form with WFFM.
Form Verification: Check User and Password
Save action: User Login with Password
And updated the Error messages for each language I have.
[image]

I also changed the error message, but when testing it out, I always get:

> We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved.

[image]

In the error log I do see the translated message.

> 21492 14:34:15 WARN  Web Forms for Marketers: an exception 'Check FR Fails' has occured while trying to execute an action ''.

**Why is the error message (Check FR Fails) not shown on the front end?**
I have the feeling that I'm missing something here. Perhaps WFFM wasn't installed correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the setting value **“Exception.HideInner”** should be set to "false" in the **\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Forms.config** in order to display this message.

Please check this community answer: https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/16/t/2309